# Processing time for Euclidean Distance

Tags: geoprocessing, distance, qgis-processing, time

I am running a Euclidean Distance analysis on a large file. I have a polygon layer that includes all Urban areas in Canada, US, and Mexico merged into one multipart polygon file. I am attempting to calculate Euclidean Distance at the 10 x 10 m pixel resolution. It has been three days, the hour glass in the results window is still there and the status bar at the bottom is still running with "Euclidean Distance...". I also set a processing extent to just outside the coastal boundary of the entire North America. Is there a way to see how much progress has been made, or how much time (or percent) is left to do? i have no idea if this is going to run for another hour or another 3 days.

Comment: I don't know QGIS to provide all the most useful information, but it strikes me that something has gone terribly terribly wrong. Are you trying to calculate the distance from one pixel to every other pixel? Also, what is the disk size of the polygon layer and how much memory do you have in your computer?

Comment: the file size (polygon multipart shapefile) is 147,495 KB and my computer has a 64 bit operating system with 48.0 GB installed RAM of which 47.9 is useable.

Comment: I have run models before that took up to 5 days and worked, usually it was the results of very large datasets or limited processing power... i was hoping the same was true in this situation. I am trying to create a raster file (10x10 m grid) where each pixel has a value for distance depending on the closest polygon (i.e. urban center).

Comment: Yeah, that's probably going to be a bunch of days to process. You're looking at something like 6 billion distance calculations and probably tens of gigs for the final raster. You might have a faster processing time if you wrote a script to parallelize it and put it on a high performance computer. Or your script might be able to make more effective use of your computer's memory (I don't know how effectively QGIS is using that memory)

Comment: Can you set a maximum distance value that would limit the processing away from urban areas? Are you ever going to need a result for cells that are beyond a certain distance that you will not use?

Comment: Also, depending on what you need it for, you might be able to get away with on-the-fly processing, which should be plenty quick.

Comment: thank you for all the helpful comments. Unfortunately, I cannot set a maximum distance, i need the analysis for the entire North America, including even the furthest regions (arctic), but what i think I can do is decrease the processing extent to just a little off the coast of north America and increase the pixel size output to 1 sq km. Thanks all.